# Add a conditional rolling count when there's mixed column data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file that looks like:

```
Timestamp       Surface_Data
8737.37         Maze_A
8737.42         Maze_A
8740.40         Phone_Surface
8743.23         Desktop_Surface
8765.26         Phone_Surface
8765.29         Maze_A
8765.30         Phone_Surface
8765.56         Maze_B
8766.16         Maze_B
8783.74         Maze_A
8793.20         Maze_A
8840.12         Phone_Surface
8840.40         Phone_Surface
8841.40         Maze_B
```

I want to a add a column that counts the change in Maze_A to Maze_B OR Maze_B to Maze_A, it has to look something like:

```
Timestamp       Surface_Data         Maze_Count
8737.37         Maze_A               1
8737.42         Maze_A
8740.40         Phone_Surface
8743.23         Desktop_Surface
8765.26         Phone_Surface
8765.29         Maze_A
8765.30         Phone_Surface
8765.56         Maze_B               2
8766.16         Maze_B
8783.74         Maze_A               3
8793.20         Maze_A
8840.12         Phone_Surface
8840.40         Phone_Surface
8841.40         Maze_B               4
```

I tried using the cumsum() when there's a change in value in the "Surface_Data" column, but it accounts all the changes including the other values that are not required. Thus, I want something that increments only when it comes across Maze_A or Maze_B value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try, filter dataframe for 'Maze_A' and 'Maze_B', look for changes using `shift` then `cumsum` and `drop_duplicates`, lastly, `assign` back to dataframe using intrinsic index alignment:

```
x = df.loc[df['Surface_Data'].isin(['Maze_A','Maze_B']), 'Surface_Data']
df.assign(Maze_count=(x != x.shift()).cumsum().drop_duplicates())
```

Output:

```
    Timestamp     Surface_Data  Maze_count
0     8737.37           Maze_A         1.0
1     8737.42           Maze_A         NaN
2     8740.40    Phone_Surface         NaN
3     8743.23  Desktop_Surface         NaN
4     8765.26    Phone_Surface         NaN
5     8765.29           Maze_A         NaN
6     8765.30    Phone_Surface         NaN
7     8765.56           Maze_B         2.0
8     8766.16           Maze_B         NaN
9     8783.74           Maze_A         3.0
10    8793.20           Maze_A         NaN
11    8840.12    Phone_Surface         NaN
12    8840.40    Phone_Surface         NaN
13    8841.40           Maze_B         4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `shift`, `where`, `cumsum`

```
s = df.Surface_Data
c = s.where(s.str.match('^Maze_[AB]$')).ffill()
d = c.ne(c.shift())

df.assign(Maze_Count=d.cumsum().where(d, ''))

    Timestamp     Surface_Data Maze_Count
0     8737.37           Maze_A          1
1     8737.42           Maze_A           
2     8740.40    Phone_Surface           
3     8743.23  Desktop_Surface           
4     8765.26    Phone_Surface           
5     8765.29           Maze_A           
6     8765.30    Phone_Surface           
7     8765.56           Maze_B          2
8     8766.16           Maze_B           
9     8783.74           Maze_A          3
10    8793.20           Maze_A           
11    8840.12    Phone_Surface           
12    8840.40    Phone_Surface           
13    8841.40           Maze_B          4
```

Answer (score 1):

One attempt:

```py
c = df['Surface_Data'].str.contains('Maze')

df['Maze_Count'] = df.loc[c, 'Surface_Data'].ne(df.loc[c, 'Surface_Data'].shift()
                                               ).astype(int).replace(0, np.nan).cumsum()
```

```
    Timestamp     Surface_Data  Maze_Count
0     8737.37           Maze_A         1.0
1     8737.42           Maze_A         NaN
2     8740.40    Phone_Surface         NaN
3     8743.23  Desktop_Surface         NaN
4     8765.26    Phone_Surface         NaN
5     8765.29           Maze_A         NaN
6     8765.30    Phone_Surface         NaN
7     8765.56           Maze_B         2.0
8     8766.16           Maze_B         NaN
9     8783.74           Maze_A         3.0
10    8793.20           Maze_A         NaN
11    8840.12    Phone_Surface         NaN
12    8840.40    Phone_Surface         NaN
13    8841.40           Maze_B         4.0
```